# SwiftData crashes app on get value: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x101e8303c)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm utilizing SwiftData in my app, and I have a `Tracker` model with two variables: `name` of type `String` and `trackerType` of type `TrackerType`, which is another model. Retrieving `name` data from the `Tracker` works fine, but attempting to read `trackerType` results in a crash with the error:

> EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x101e8303c).

Here's my Tracker Model:

```
@Model
class Tracker {
    var name: String
    var trackerType: [TrackerType]

    init(name: String, trackerType: [TrackerType]) {
        self.name = name
        self.trackerType = trackerType
    }
}

@Model
class TrackerType {
    var type: String
    var status: Bool

    init(type: String, status: Bool) {
        self.type = type
        self.status = status
    }
}
```

And the crash result snippest:
[image: Crash]

I don't understand what could be the issue. I attempted to create the model with dummy data locally in my application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420385/crashes-when-accessing-swiftdata-model-in-view-after-its-been-decoded-from-json ? Is there an error message in Console?

Comment: Console is empty, no error message

Comment: I've identified a solution and written down in the answer section. However, I am open to accepting alternative answers that have also resolved my issue.

Comment: Add the code where you create, connect and saves the objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After dedicating the entire day to investigating, I've identified the root cause of the error.

The issue lies in the inability to read model data without prior saving it in the SwiftData container. Therefore, the necessary steps are as follows:

- Avoid using the locally created dummy data model directly.
- Initially, **save the data in the container**.
- Retrieve and use the data from the container.

So, my code after following those steps is like below:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct DashboardView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [TrackerItem]
    @AppStorage("DataSaved") private var isDummyDataSavedOnce = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            if isDummyDataSavedOnce, let item = items.first  {
                TrackerView(prayers: item.tracker)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            saveDummyData()
        }
    }

    private func saveDummyData() {
        if !isDummyDataSavedOnce {
            withAnimation {
                let newItem = TrackerDummyData.trackerItem
                modelContext.insert(newItem)
                isDummyDataSavedOnce.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding and saving irrelevant data is not a good solution, please add the requested information to your question so it's possible to proved a proper solution

Comment: In short, we can't access the relationship model without first inserting the new model to the container. Thank you for finding the solution for us!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used a separate `@Published` storage

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var currentlyDisplayedList: [Block] = []

}

@Model
final class Block: Identifiable {

    let name: String
    let questions: [Question]
```

SwiftUI View was

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
/// ...
    ForEach(blocks) { block in
       DisclosureTableRow(TableItemWrapper.block(block)) {
          ForEach(block.questions) { question in
```

when I changed storage container into

```
@Query private var blocks: [Block]
```

inside the view the crash dissapeared.